# Relationship between the power of a convex lens and the refractive index of a medium

Tags: optics, refraction, lenses

According to the [Lensmaker's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens#Lensmaker%27s_equation),

$$\frac{1}{f} = (μ-1)\left(\frac{1}{R_1} - \frac{1}{R_2}\right)$$

Apparently, focal length $f$ is inversely proportional to the refractive index of the medium $μ$. Since, Optical Power $P = \frac{1}{f}$. This should imply that optical power is directly proportional to the refractive index. However, today I got told by my teacher that these two are independent. Where have I gone wrong in my reasoning? Is the fact provided to me correct and if yes, how?

Comment: Please talk to your teacher and present your formula.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your teacher thought about while saying this, but this is not true. The power of the lens does depend on the refractive index $\mu_{lm}=\mu_l/\mu_m$ of the lens which is clear from the formula, you have given.
$$P=\frac{1}{f}=(\mu_{lm}-1)\left( \frac{1}{R_1}-\frac{1}{R_2}\right)$$

Comment: I understand that, another side question though. We know that, for a thin lens, $f=\frac{R}{2}$. The lens is cut off from a bigger sphere with radius $R$. I gather that it is because of the light rays bending earlier in a denser region leading to the point of focus being a bit nearer.   Am I right? Do the dimensions of that bigger sphere from which the lens was cut off appear to be apparently differently as well, so the apparent radius changes as well?

Comment: "for a thin lens, =/2" Not so. This relationship is for a concave mirror of large radius of curvature.